# JavaScript Post Form Does Not Redirect

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to post a form with JavaScript.
Page I'm posting normally returns a redirect with .request_id appended.
When I do it manually it works but with:

```
document.forms["formId"].submit();
```

it gives me response from the site with all the data written out in the fields but it doesn't post.

Can this be done?
To be more clear:

action URL with in the form is something like this:

```
action="http://www.someurl.com/path/to/page.jsp?_DARGS=value"
```

Than when I post manually site redirects me and form submission is a sucess with the URL looking like this:

```
http://www.someurl.com/path/to/page.jsp?request_id=87475
```

However when I do it trough JavaScript it gets me to the page but no redirection, URL is the same as in the form action attribute.

```
http://www.someurl.com/path/to/page.jsp?_DARGS=value
```

and the form is not submitted just displayed again with fields filled in.
So the question is: what is the difference, why does it not redirect with JavaScript?

I would prefer plain JavaScript if it can but I can use jQuery too if this is the only option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

The reason form submission acted different was because when JavaScript submit() function is used all the fields in the form are sent but not submit field itself.

This is not sent in the request header:

```
<input type="submit" name="somename" value="value" />
```

Workaround is to use JavaScript click() function or to make a hidden field with the same name="value" as submit field.

Answer (score 0):

Find your form in your on page and then Submit it by following code

```
document.getElementById("formId").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rMqr7/2/).

```
<form name="formName" id="formId"></form>
```

```
console.log(document.forms['formName']);
console.log(document.forms['formId']);
```

I am using the latest version of Chrome, and both of those are selecting the current form.  This means that (at least in my browser) one can select a form by ID or by name using the method that you have used.

This leads me to believe there may be a problem somewhere else in your code, and that **your current code is correct. A common issue is calling a JavaScript method before the DOM has loaded.**

To remedy this:

Either ensure all of your code is at the end of the `<body>`:

```
<!-- your HTML, then... -->

    <script>
        // your code
    </script>
</body>
```

Or, put your code in an `onload` handler:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // your code
};
```

As you did mention jQuery in your post, include jQuery in your document, and then call:

```
$(function() {
    // your code
});
```

Comment: The code was all ready at the end of the <body> tag. Form does get sent but when I do it manually site I'm sending the form returns redirect. With JavScript does not redirect me. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('formID').submit();
```

for your code it would work with the form name like this:

```
document.forms['formName'].submit();
```

Comment: You might have a typo. `getElementById` does not take a CSS ID selector. It should be `getElemetById('formID')`.